# TensorFlow trained model detecting every object as trained object

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, object-detection-api

I have trained a faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco model for two objects Lion and Ostrich with 180-200 images for each object. After training, the model is detecting every object as either lion or ostrich irrespective of the object in the image. Example: It is detecting elephant as both lion and ostrich. Can someone suggest a solution for this.